# sorting records according to datetime in asp.net from postgresql DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, npgsql

I want to select the most recent videos from "Videos" table. I'm using PostgreSql Db and Npgsql data provider. My app is in Asp.net.

The userids are in the List - userid_list. Whichever person's id is in the list, only their videos need to be sorted.

Im storing all the records returned by the query in List called "videos_list".

The problem is that the videos are getting sorted by the userids,ie, videos are in desc order for one id and then the next and so on but i dont want that. I want to retrieve all the videos for those ids and then sort everything at once.

```
    string query3 = "Select * from \"Videos\" where \"User_ID\" = :user_id Order by \"DateTimeUploaded\" desc"; 

    NpgsqlCommand cmd3 = new NpgsqlCommand(query3, con);


     for (int j = 0; j < userid_list.Count; j++)
     {
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("user_id", userid_list[j]);
            reader2 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader2.Read())
            {
                string Description = reader2.GetString(reader2.GetOrdinal("Description"));

                DateTime DateTimeUploaded = reader2.GetDateTime(reader2.GetOrdinal("DateTimeUploaded"));

                videos_list.Add(new VideosJson(Description, Transcript, ThumbnailUrl, VideoUrl, DateTimeUploaded));

            }
     }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've designed it so that you're looping through users and retrieving *their* videos in descending order, and then adding those to the list as a group.

```
User 1
    Video 3
    Video 2
    Video 1

User 2
    Video 6
    Video 5
    Video 4
```

You should do one of the following

1. Amend your SQL command to filter for all users at once (i.e. `"User_ID" = A or "User_ID" = B ...` then order by time.
2. Add your results (in any order) to one big list and *then* sort it by descending time, although this is less gracious.

Comment: Thnx @Jimmy..your explanation makes it very simple to understand what's happening. It'd be a gr8 help if u could tell me how to do what u hv asked me to do..:)

Comment: Figured it out...the main prob was bcoz i was storing the IDs in a list....needed to use Inner Join! Inner Joined 2 tables 2 get the userids and then again inner joined that to get the videos with those ids in desc order..